# pushing the specific table row data to a dialog in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a table that retrieves data from a json called `approvalsData` with fields `name`, `type`, and `owners`. Table pulls the data just fine. And the dialog opens. But I can't figure out how to pull that row data in the dialog. Not the entire json data, just the row I am clicking on.

What am I missing here? I'm guessing a lot :)

```
<TableBody>
    {approvalsData.map( (row, index) => (
        <TableRow
            key={index}
            onTouchTap={this.handleApprovalDialogOpen}>
            <TableRowColumn>{row.name}</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{row.type}</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{row.owner}</TableRowColumn>

            <Dialog
                modal={false}
                contentStyle={dialogStyle}
                open={this.state.open}
                onRequestClose={this.handleApprovalDialogClose}>

                <Col key={index}>
                    <div>Name: <span>{this.name}</span></div>
                    <div>Type: <span>{this.type}</span></div>
                    <div>Owner: <span>{this.owner}</span></div>
                </Col>
            </Dialog>
        </TableRow>
    ))}
</TableBody>
```

**UPDATE**

Inspecting the source, I realized that by including the Dialog inside the loop, I was displaying a dialog for every instance of the table rows. No wonder I was just seeing the last one. The others were behind it lol. ANyway, I moved it outside of the loop but now I can't reach the table row data from the table itself. I can reach the data by pointing to the json itself. The example below is showing the first index in the json, but that is not what I want. I want to show the row that I want to click on.

```
<TableBody>
    {approvalsData.map( (row, index) => (
        <TableRow
            key={index}
            onTouchTap={this.handleApprovalDialogOpen}>
            <TableRowColumn>{row.name}</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{row.type}</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{row.owner}</TableRowColumn>

        </TableRow>
    ))}
</TableBody>
<Dialog
    modal={false}
    contentStyle={dialogStyle}
    open={this.state.open}
    onRequestClose={this.handleApprovalDialogClose}>

    <Col>
        <div>Name: <span>{approvalsData[0].name}</span></div>
        <div>Type: <span>{approvalsData[0].type}</span></div>
        <div>Owner: <span>{approvalsData[0].owner}</span></div>
    </Col>
</Dialog>
```

See the [**webpackbin**](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kl1nXjPg9gXjQYaffcY)

Thanks in advance

Comment: wouldn't using `{row.name}` instead of `{this.name}` just work?

Comment: I thought it would, but it give me the last row :/

Comment: I updated my answer. That explains why I was getting the last one only. You're right. `row.name` works but it still shows all of my records. I only want one. The one I am clicking on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mukesh's approach looks solid.  You're probably getting undefined because you're trying to access approvalsData with an index that does not exist.  Try his solution and add:

```
<TableBody>
    {approvalsData.map( (row, index) => (
        <TableRow
            key={index}
            onTouchTap={(e) => this.handleApprovalDialogOpen(index, e)}>
            <TableRowColumn>{row.name}</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{row.type}</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{row.owner}</TableRowColumn>
        </TableRow>
    ))}
</TableBody>
```

Comment: Still getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined. I'm going to build a webpackbin in the morning so that you guys can have a better environment to check it out

Comment: Can you print this.state of your component and paste it here?

Comment: Actually, I didn't wait until the morning. I'm updating the question with a webpackbin.

Comment: [It should be working now](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kl1s3eo1NTLRXMCG-Z7). There were two problems I did not foresee.  One, on the initial render, openIndex is not defined so you cannot access the name property.  State updates are batched as well, so setting the state of the open property in the callback to the set index ensures that the open state is never set before the index state.  Another guard is in the render, which ensures that the modal is not rendered before the state is set to open, which can only happen after the indexState is set.

Comment: Outstanding! Thanks a lot man! I have one more thing I need on this but I have to post it as a separate question. Basically, I need to be able to pull the next row data from inside the dialog with an arrow right and the previous with an arrow left. I'll update this in a separate webpackbin. Hopefully you spot it and can help me with it. But I'm going to try to figure it out myself first of course. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you set the `open` state in `handleApprovalDialogOpen` callback. You can bind the callback to the index (or id if any) of the row.

```
// some code
        onTouchTap={this.handleApprovalDialogOpen.bind(this, index)}

<Dialog
    modal={false}
    contentStyle={dialogStyle}
    open={this.state.open}
    onRequestClose={this.handleApprovalDialogClose}>

    <Col>
        <div>Name: <span>{approvalsData[this.state.openRowIndex].name}</span></div>
        <div>Type: <span>{approvalsData[this.state.openRowIndex].type}</span></div>
        <div>Owner: <span>{approvalsData[this.state.openRowIndex].owner}</span></div>
    </Col>
</Dialog>

handleApprovalDialogOpen(rowIndex, event) {
  this.setState({open: true, openRowIndex: rowIndex})
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` error. Will this work with the dialog inside or outside of the loop? See my two code samples. The first one resulted in all of the dialogs opening

Comment: It should work. Looks like your `this` reference in the place you are declaring the Dialog is not correct. What method/function are you creating Dialog inside?

Comment: i'm not sure I follow. "What method/function are you creating Dialog inside?"  The dialog is from material ui. It's a normal div once it renders. I'm not creating it by any method, if that's what you mean.

Comment: are you doing that in render method?

Comment: when it says `name of undefined`, it means that it cannot find the state property on `this`, which means `this` is not referring to the element created by using your component

Comment: I have the Dialog outside of the .map. My guess is, since it's outside of the map, it's outside of the focus of the data being mapped into the table rows. But I am reaching the data if I call the json.name  itself. For instance `{approvalsData[0].name}` works for reaching data. But it is calling for the first record. `{approvalsData[this.state.openRowIndex].name}` doesn't work because it can't find name. This is with the Dialog outside the map. I can try moving the dialog inside the map again and see if that works. But originally it was rendering a dialog for every table row when DOM ready

Comment: I moved it inside the TableRow as my first block of code above and tried your code and it still gave me name of undefined.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your initial help. Stephen was able to put it together for me. But you did contribute to it. Shame I can't award both of you with an answer +1